# How do I set a user lookup field equal to the owner using a trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a field called Account_Manager__c on my Account record and I am trying to set it equal to the Account Owner when certain rules are met. I got the concept to work when I was just updating a text field but I'm getting a NullPointerException when I try to update the user lookup field.

Here is my code:

```
trigger updateAM on Account (before update) {    
    for (Account acct: trigger.new){  
        if(acct.Owner_AM__c == 0){   
            if(acct.Owner_Role__c == 'Affiliate Team'){   
                acct.Account_Manager__r.Id = acct.Owner.Id;   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

__r refers to the relationship in a lookup or master-detail relationship. Use the field name, in this case, if you want to write a new value to it. Use Account_Manager__r if you want to read fields on that related object. Furthermore, you want to use *account.OwnerId* and not account.Owner.Id.

Try `account.Account_Manager__c = account.OwnerId;`

Comment: Thanks Matt, it worked! The only thing changed is instead of putting "account." I used "acct." since thats what I named my account object in the 2nd row.

Answer (score 2):

Although @MattThomas has the correct answer, the reason for your null pointer exception is a common misconception about what is in a trigger's context.

When a trigger is invoked, the trigger code only has access to the fields on the SObject. No parent fields, no children fields

Hence, `acct.Account_Manager__r.Id` throws the NPE because the relationship `account__r` is not available to the trigger.

Note this is different when using formula fields where the relationships do exist and can be used; same for workflow and process flow conditional expressions

If one needs in a trigger the value of parent or children fields, they have to be queried for in the trigger.